# Replacing the location of images in Google-Earth

Tags: google-earth

A friend of mine inherited (don't ask about the specifics here) a documentation on Google Earth which incorporates a lot of images. Those where on a server and accessed from there.

Now the server has been shutdown, so the web-links are gone. Nevertheless the images are still available as the server data has been secured. The links in GE are now marked as invalid, and I can see that there are web-links in the form of `https://domain.tld/directory/image.jpg` in the app.

So I am looking for a solution to extract the data to be able to replace the `https://domain.tld/directory`-part, replace it with an appropriate local directory (`C:\directory\`) and then reload it back into the GE.

Or is there any internal function/tool available in GE?

(IT-knowledge to a certain extent to make conversions is available.)

Comment: If you're willing to write a few lines of python code then pykml module should be relatively simple to rewrite the link location and output a new KML file. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273278/parsing-xml-with-pykml/63527853#63527853).

Comment: Sound interesting. Do you have any idea where I can locate the file with the links, resp. how I can export and import/replace them?

Comment: If the data with links is in Google Earth then you can right-click on it and select "Save Place As" (then select .kml as save-as type) to export the KML. With KML in a file, you can next try to parse it which is just a text XML file.

Answer (score 0):

If by "documentation on Google Earth" you mean a KML file, then yes, you should be able to update the URLs relatively easily.  a KML file is just an XML text file, so you can open it up with any text editor.  If you use a full featured text editor then you can do a find/replace on the "https://domain.tld/directory/" part, and replace it with something that looks like: "file:///C:/directory/".

Where you find the URLs will depend on whether the images are used as ground overlays, icons, content in balloons associated with placemarks, etc.